# Read files from multiple directories in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I need to read files from multiple directories and than process and store the data into DB.
Currently i am using chunk multiple resource reader and it is working fine for 1 directory.
But now i have to read files from multiple directories.
How to do it using spring batch

Comment: You should just need the correct expression...

Comment: @MichaelMinella . If all the directories don't have same parent directory. If 1st directory is like /usr/local/usecase1/dir1 and 2nd directory like /usr/local/usecase2/dir2 and also we don't know the number of directory that will be given fron outside at run time

Comment: In that case, create a FactoryBean that returns a Resource[].  That's really all the MultiReaourceItReader uses anyways.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @MichaelMinella

Answer (score 4):

You can use MultiResourceItemReader along with Step Scope. 
using StepScop late binding you can inject file location

```
MultiResourceItemReader<> multiResourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
    ClassLoader cLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(cLoader);
    resources = resolver.getResources("file:" + FileLocationAsVaribale);
    multiResourceItemReader.setResources(resources);
    multiResourceItemReader.setDelegate(yourReader());
```